# How to call a function when Get-Content reads a line

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I am setting up a script that will send me an email every time a certain log file is written to but when Get-Content reads a new line, the pipe does not call the sendmail function.

The sendmail function is defined before the following line and successfully sends me an email by itself.

`Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait app.log | sendmail`

Comment: What is the sendmail function?  Does it have a process block?

Comment: I don't know what a process block is. The sendmail function follows this format: 
`$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mysmtp -Credential $cred -UseSsl -From 'myemail@domain.com' -To 'toemail@domain.com' -Subject 'TEST'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn what a process block is.  It runs for every element piped in.  Put your code in the process block, and it will do what you want, as someone else already answered.  Process blocks are really important in powershell.

```
function hi { 
  process { 
   'hi' 
  } 
}

Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait app.log | hi
hi
hi
hi
```

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. There is no guidance as to how to implement this to solve his question

Comment: Actually it is helpful. Process blocks are a core PowerShell concept that, when understood, can assist the OP with framing his question.

Comment: Answer is more helpful now after the edit @Bill_Stewart . It previously only showed the function with little explanation and was harder to understand. The answer still doesn't provide specifics but is close enough. I'll retract my downvote.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have tried a process block and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You should get the value from the pipeline through a process block:

```
function sendmail {
    process {
        $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force 
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd) 
        Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mysmtp -Credential $cred -UseSsl -From 'myemail@domain.com' -To 'toemail@domain.com' -Subject 'TEST'
    }
}
```

This will tell PowerShell that you want this section of code to run for every object passed on the pipeline (every line in this case). If you want to access the current object from inside the process block, use `$_` as a variable.

See [Piping Objects to Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6#piping-objects-to-functions)